# Normed space of bounded functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X = \{f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}: \exists M\in\mathbb{N} \forall n\in\mathbb{N} f(n) \leq M\}$.

Define a norm on $X$ by defining for $f\in X$: $$||f|| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{2^n}.$$

Is the metric space associated $(X,||\cdot ||)$ complete? What about compactness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is not really a norm (because $X$ is not even an abelian group) nevertheless $X$ can be always seen as a metric space with the following distance :

$$d(f,g):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|f(n)-g(n)|}{2^n} $$

I think now of $X$ with the distance written above.  Define a sequence $(f_k)$ :

$$f_k(n):=n\text{ if } n\leq k\text{ and } 0 \text{ if } n>k $$

Then $f_k\in X$ (it is obvious) furthermore, if $k\leq l$ then :

$$d(f_k,f_l)=\sum_{n=k+1}^l\frac{n}{2^n}\leq \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n} $$

The last part converging toward $0$ when $k$ goes to infinity independently of $l$. This shows that $(f_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Now, here is an aside affirmation that is easily verified :

> If $(g_k)$ converges in $X$ toward $g$ then $g_k(n)\rightarrow_k g(n)$ in $\mathbb{N}$ for any $n$.

Now, assume that our sequence $(f_k)$ had a limit $f$ then, by what is written above : $f(n)=lim_kf_k(n)$. It is clear that $lim_kf_k(n)=n$ so that the limit function sends any integer $n$ to itself. But this function is not bounded hence it is not in $X$, this shows that the Cauchy sequence $(f_k)$ does not converge hence $X$ is not complete and in particular not compact.

Comment: @AlexandreHalm, $(X,+)$ is a commutative monoid with a unit if $+$ is defined by $(f+g)(n):=f(n)+g(n)$. However the function constant equal to $1$ has no inverse in $X$ because the inverse should be the function constant equal to $-1$ and $-1$ is not in $\mathbb{N}$. Now if we slightly change $X$ and ask for the functions to go in $\mathbb{Z}$ and change the norm to add the absolute value, the distance I defined is $d(f,g):=\| f-g\|$ as you said... I think this is what the OP means with "the metric space associated to $(X,\|.\|)$".

Comment: Very nicely written, thanks Clément!